# Amazon Redshift data sharing feature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift data sharing, if I change the definition of a table or view in the producer cluster by adding a column etc., will it be automatically reflected in the table or view of the data sharing area?

I will add an object to the data sharing area with ALTER DATASHARE ~ ADD TABLE, but if I change the definition, do I need to enter the above command again?

If you have any idea, I would appreciate it if you could answer.

I'm not used to English, so I'm sorry if it's a strange English sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the table/view by adding or removing columns it will be reflected automatically on the consumer: no need to alter the datashare.
However if you rename the table/view you will have to add it to the datashare objects.

Comment: Wow, the data sharing function is very convenient. Thank you very much!!